# How to uninstall Ubuntu from Windows 7?

Tags: uninstall

I have nothing against Ubuntu. Completely satisfied with its performance. But after some while now, I don't have much hard disk space for my own files. So I'm planning to keep Windows 7 and uninstall Ubuntu.

Currently I get dual boot options when I turn on my PC. I got to know that uninstalling Ubuntu would result in some repair work to be done for Windows 7. Please fill me in with details on this, and on how to uninstall Ubuntu, because I have an uninstall file in Windows 7 in the location where I have installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isnt very clear, but it SOUNDS like you installed via **WUBI**, i.e you installed from within windows using a setup wizard that poped up when you inserted the CD (or mounted the ISO) in this case you can just **uninstall it like any other windows software** - Uninstall using the link in start if any or from Add/Remove Programs. **No other steps**.

Comment: thank you.. I installed it by downloading it directly. got no CDs for ubuntu.. all i want to know is that if i uninstall ubuntu, will windows 7 need repair do be done using windows 7 boot CD??

Comment: if you have an option to "Uninstall" ubuntu from windows from Add/Remove Programs, you can do it with no additional steps/repair required

Comment: thank you man.. just one more doubt,it works the same way with the ubuntu uninstall file??

Comment: yup, I expect Add/Remove Programs would just redirect to this file

Comment: yeah it worked !! it took just a few seconds to uninstall ubuntu completely!! now i just have to check the boot screen by restarting my PC

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu from Windows with **wubi** then just run uninstall file.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple. Go to **Add and Remove Programme** Find Ubuntu and Uninstall.

Comment: Accept it if your problem has been solved